# Fooman PDF Customiser

Tags: invoice

I am using the extenstion Fooman PDF Customiser. It works fine, but i want change some text in my invoice.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as this is a question for our support team.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for using Pdf Customiser. This site is not really meant for support of a 3rd party commercial extension but to answer your question - it depends which text you want to change specifically. Please email us at support@fooman.co.nz what you want to customise and we will be able to help you further.

Nearly all the output is run through Magento's translation system so this might be an easy way to change it. Alternatively the text might already come from a back-end setting and/or can be changed in the phtml template files that drive the layout of the pdfs.